# automation of data format conversion to parent child format

Tags: java, excel, vbscript, automation

This is an excel sheet which has only a single column filled for each row.
(explanation : all CITY categories fall under V21 , all handset categories fall under CityJ and so on )

```
   V21                  
       CITYR
       CITYJ
           HandsetS
           HandsetHW
           HandsetHA
               LOWER_AGE<=20
               LOWER_AGE>20     
                   SMS_COUNT<=0 
                       RECHARGE_MRP<=122
                       RECHARGE_MRP>122
                   SMS_COUNT>0
```

I need to change this format to a double column format 
with parent and child category format.
therefore
the output sheet would be

```
    V21           CITYR
    V21           CITYJ
    CITYJ         HandsetS
    CITYJ         HandsetHW
    CITYJ         HandsetHA
    HandsetHA     LOWER_AGE<=20
    HandsetHA     LOWER_AGE>20      
    LOWER_AGE>20    SMS_COUNT<=0    
    SMS_COUNT<=0    RECHARGE_MRP<=122
    SMS_COUNT<=0    RECHARGE_MRP>122
    LOWER_AGE>20    SMS_COUNT>0
```

the datas are huge so i cant do them manually . how can i automate this ?

Comment: You mentioned "datas are huge", bur since this is excel document, I assume it does not have more than 65535 rows. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 parts of the task so I want to know what is that you are asking help about.

1. Reading excel sheet data into Java
2. Manipulating data
3. Writing data back into the excel sheet.

You have said that the data sheet is large and cannot be pulled as a whole into memory. Can I ask you how many top level elements do you have ? i.e, How many V21s do you have? If it is just ONE, then how many CITYR/CITYJ do you have?

--

Adding some source code from my previous answer about how to manipulate data. I gave it an input file which was separated by tabs (4 spaces equals to one column for you in excel) and the following code printed stuff out neatly. Please note that there is a condition of level == 1 left empty. If you think ur JVM has too many objects, you could clear the entries and stack at that point :)

```
package com.ekanathk;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.junit.Test;

class Entry {
    private String input;
    private int level;
    public Entry(String input, int level) {
        this.input = input;
        this.level = level;
    }
    public String getInput() {
        return input;
    }
    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Entry [input=" + input + ", level=" + level + "]";
    }
}

public class Tester {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Tester.class.getName());

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Test
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {

        InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("samplecsv.txt");
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String input = null;
        List entries = new ArrayList();
        Stack<Entry> stack = new Stack<Entry>();
        stack.push(new Entry("ROOT", -1));
        while((input = b.readLine()) != null){
            int level = whatIsTheLevel(input);
            input = input.trim();
            logger.info("input = " + input + " at level " + level); 
            Entry entry = new Entry(input, level);
            if(level == 1) {
                //periodically clear out the map and write it to another excel sheet
            }
            if (stack.peek().getLevel() == entry.getLevel()) {
                stack.pop();
            }
            Entry parent = stack.peek();
            logger.info("parent = " + parent);
            entries.add(new String[]{parent.getInput(), entry.getInput()});
            stack.push(entry);
        }
        for(Object entry : entries) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString((String[])entry));
        }
    }

    private int whatIsTheLevel(String input) {
        int numberOfSpaces = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if(input.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                return numberOfSpaces/4;
            } else {
                numberOfSpaces++;
            }
        }
        return numberOfSpaces/4;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This considers that you have a file small enough to fit in computer memory. Even 10MB file should be good.

It has 2 parts:

DataTransformer which does all the
   required transformation of data

TreeNode is custom simple Tree data
   structure

```
public class DataTransformer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = DataTransformer.class
                .getResourceAsStream("source_data.tab");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line;
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode("ROOT", Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        TreeNode currentNode = root;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            int level = getLevel(line);
            String value = line.trim();
            TreeNode nextNode = new TreeNode(value, level);
            relateNextNode(currentNode, nextNode);
            currentNode = nextNode;
        }
        printAll(root);
    }

    public static int getLevel(String line) {
        final char TAB = '\t';
        int numberOfTabs = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            if (line.charAt(i) != TAB) {
                break;
            }
            numberOfTabs++;
        }
        return numberOfTabs;
    }

    public static void relateNextNode(
            TreeNode currentNode, TreeNode nextNode) {
        if (currentNode.getLevel() < nextNode.getLevel()) {
            currentNode.addChild(nextNode);
        } else {
            relateNextNode(currentNode.getParent(), nextNode);
        }
    }

    public static void printAll(TreeNode node) {
        if (!node.isRoot() && !node.getParent().isRoot()) {
            System.out.println(node);
        }
        for (TreeNode childNode : node.getChildren()) {
            printAll(childNode);
        }
    }
}

class TreeNode implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private TreeNode parent;
    private List<TreeNode> children = new ArrayList<TreeNode>();
    private String value;
    private int level;

    public TreeNode(String value, int level) {
        this.value = value;
        this.level = level;
    }

    public void addChild(TreeNode child) {
        child.parent = this;
        this.children.add(child);
    }

    public void addSibbling(TreeNode sibbling) {
        TreeNode parent = this.parent;
        parent.addChild(sibbling);
    }

    public TreeNode getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public List<TreeNode> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public boolean isRoot() {
        return this.parent == null;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String str;
        if (this.parent != null) {
            str = this.parent.value + '\t' + this.value;
        } else {
            str = this.value;
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```